# Is it safe to use prepend_before_action for Devise authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a [scenario](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31259) where it would be useful to use `prepend_before_action :authenticate_user!` instead of the usual `before_action :authenticate_user!`.

I would like to know if it is possible / safe to use `prepend_before_action`for Devise. My worry is that maybe Devise already uses `prepend_before_action` for other filters that must be run before `:authenticate_user!`.

Comment: Are you trying to run `set_time_zone` before or after `authenticate_user!`. It's a little confusing.

Comment: `set_time_zone` must be run after `authenticate_user!` and that's why I would like to use `prepend_before_action :authenticate_user!`.

Comment: After some reasoning, probably using `prepend_before_action` is not safe. See [my comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4713#issuecomment-348508636)